# PHP replace all

Tags: php, replace

I have this in JavaScript:

```
msg = msg.replace(/(:\)|=\)|:-\)|\(:)/gi, "<img src='img/ei/1.png' class='ei' />");
```

Is there a similar way I can do that, but in PHP?

Thanks in advance, enji

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly the same way:

```
$msg = preg_replace('/(:\)|=\)|:-\)|\(:)/i', "<img src='img/ei/1.png' class='ei' />", $msg);
```

Comment: @enjikaka if the answer worked, consider accepting it so that next time someone looks for this type of problem, he will be able to notice it quickly.

Comment: I tried before you sent the message, but it was before it let me to (5 minutes haven't gone yet) :P

Comment: @enjikaka: You don't even need a regular expression for this. See Shai Mishali's answer. Try avoiding regexes when you can, they are difficult to read, and they are slow.

Comment: @greg0ire so his will be faster?

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly you are trying to replace instances of the :\ smiley with an image.
You could do something like this:

```php
<?php
    $str = "Hey there :)";

    str_replace(
      array(":)", "=)", ":-)", "(:"), 
      "<img src='img/ei/1.png' class='ei' />", 
      $str);
?>
```

Shai.

Comment: Notice: that is a regular expression, '\' is used to escape reserved characters, like ')'.

Comment: Still the solution would work the same way just for :) , =), :-)  and :)

Comment: You missed the "(:" smiley from your expression.

Comment: Deejavy, I think the "Technique" is understandable enough, Stackoverflow isn't about writing code for people, its about helping them understand which techniques to use in their code.

Comment: So would you say this is faster then the one with regex?

Comment: Regex is always considered a bit "Slower", and i don't think that for such a simple operation you would really need it.

Comment: Quoting the [str_replace manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()

Comment: @jedi Wow, 3 years later :)