# Is there replace function in php? like javascript replace()

Tags: javascript, php

JAVASCRIPT

```
var lblname = "Location Details";

console.log(lblname.replace(/[/\. ,:-]+/g, "-"));
```

i got Result `Location-Details`.. and as same opertaion how to do in php is there any php function available for this action?

Comment: you search in google and you will get it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
check this also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP replace all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026359/php-replace-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 <?php 
    $lblname ="Location Details";
    echo preg_replace("/[\/\\. ,:-]+/","-",$lblname);
    die;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace will be what you need

```
echo preg_replace("/[\/\\. ,:-]+/","-",$lblname);
```